# Is it possible for a module of a multi module project to use the repository folder of another?

Tags: spring-boot, repository, pom.xml, multi-module, application.properties

I was following a tutorial to learn multi-modules in maven, but what was being presented raised a question:

Is there a possibility to create a multi-module project where only one module accesses the database and the others use this connection for their respective controllers?

Basically what I want is to use the same repository folder to scan with each datasourceconfig in all modules.

The structure I imagined and even started to implement was:

```
|--main
|  |--moduleOne
|  |--|--Java
|  |-----|-DataSource
|  |-----|-models
|  |-----|-repositories
|  |--|--Resources
|  |-----|-application.properties
|  |--moduleN
|  |--|--Java
|  |-----|-controller
|  |-----|-service
|  |--|--Resources
|  |-----|-application.properties
```

The first module run perfectyly, the other need a conetion and I did It, but when I run, this module use a h2 database or not connect because moduleOne is using repository folder.
How can I fix for that services access those repositories?

POM ModuleOne

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>sig</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <artifactId>moduleOne</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>moduleOne</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SQL DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>moduleOne</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

POM ModuleN

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>sig</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <artifactId>moduleN</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>moduleN</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MODULE ON WHICH IT DEPENDS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.sig</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleOne</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>moduleN</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: i think the problem in same naming of application.properties for all modules try to use different name of properties files for different modules.

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi I renamed all properties to ModuleN.properties (ps. 'N' is a variable) and this error occurred:

"The bean 'RepositoryX', defined in br.example.sig.moduleone.repositories.RepositoryX defined in EnableJpaRepositories declared on ServiceX, could not be registered.
A bean with that name has already been defined in br.example.sig.moduleone.repositories.RepositoryX defined in EnableJpaRepositories declared on DatasourceConfig and overriding is disabled.
Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"

Comment: I renamed the anotation @Bean(name = "DataSource") to @Bean(name = "moduleNDataSource") and write spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true in all moduleN.properties but continued show this.

Comment: I think first you need create class with Configuration annotation, add PropertySource annotation with name of property file as value. After that you need to add sping.factories file to ../resources/META-INF/spring.factories with e.g
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=<path to your configuration file>
Check how i do autoconfiguration here
https://github.com/ishikawayoshi/filewatcher_monitor

Comment: Thank you for help.
I had a service with the annotations "@EntityScan" and "@EnableJpaRepositories" pointing to the same directory as my datasource in one of the modules, I put it there and forgot it.
I deleted the annotations, that was what generated the conflict and not the use for different modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The bean 'RepositoryX', defined in
> br.example.sig.moduleone.repositories.RepositoryX defined in
> EnableJpaRepositories declared on ServiceX, could not be registered. A
> bean with that name has already been defined in
> br.example.sig.moduleone.repositories.RepositoryX defined in
> EnableJpaRepositories declared on DatasourceConfig and overriding is
> disabled.
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"

I had a service with the annotations "@EntityScan" and "@EnableJpaRepositories" pointing to the same directory as my datasource in one of the modules, I put it there and forgot it.
I deleted the annotations, that was what generated the conflict and not the use for different modules.